# Перебор объектов хранящихся в ArayList, который храниться в HashMap - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку.
Необходимо отобразить значения полей объектов item которые хранятся в ArrayList monthReport.
monthReport в свою очередь храниться в HashMap monthReports.
Перебор HashMap получилось сделать, а вот перебор внутри ArrayList поему-то не получается.
Ошибка IDE:
java: for-each not applicable to expression type
required: array or java.lang.Iterable
found:    java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Integer,java.util.ArrayList>

```html
public class ReadAndShow {
    private String name;
    private String isExpence;
    private String price;
    private String quantity;

    Map<Integer, ArrayList> monthReports = new HashMap<>();   // Все месячные отчеты
    ArrayList<Item> monthReport = new ArrayList<>();  // Очет за месяц

    ReadAndShow(String name, String isExpense, String price, String quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isExpence = isExpense;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void readFileContentsOrNull() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            String address = "resources/m.20210" + i + ".csv";
            try {
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(address));
                String line;
                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String razdel = ",";
                    monthReport.add(new Item(line.split(razdel)[0], line.split(razdel)[1], line.split(razdel)[2], line.split(razdel)[2]));
                    monthReports.put(i, monthReport);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Невозможно прочитать файл с месячным отчётом. Возможно, файл не находится в нужной директории.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void showReports() {

      for (Map.Entry <Integer, ArrayList> monthReport : monthReports.entrySet()) {
         for (Item item: monthReport){   // в этой строке ошибка
                System.out.println(item.giveName());
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно типизировать ArrayList в Map. Дженерик вполне может быть вложенный.
monthReports.entrySet() - этот вызов возвращает entrySet, который по сути является пара (один ключ-значение из Map), а вы делаете так: for (Item item: monthReport), таким образом вы пытаетесь привести entrySet к Item , коим он не является. Пробуйте так:

```
public class ReadAndShow {

    private String name;
    private String isExpence;
    private String price;
    private String quantity;

    private Map<Integer, List<Item>> monthReports = new HashMap<>();   // Все месячные отчеты
    private List<Item> monthReport = new ArrayList<>();  // Очет за месяц

    ReadAndShow(String name, String isExpense, String price, String quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isExpence = isExpense;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void readFileContentsOrNull() {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("resources/m.20210" + i + ".csv"));
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    String[] split = scanner.next().split(",");
                    monthReport.add(new Item(split[0], split[1], split[2], split[2]));
                    monthReports.put(i, monthReport);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Невозможно прочитать файл с месячным отчётом. Возможно, файл не находится в нужной директории.");
        }
    }

    public void showReports() {

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Item>> monthReport : monthReports.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(monthReport.getKey());
            for (Item item : monthReport.getValue()) {
                System.out.println(item.giveName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Кроме того,вызывать каждый раз вызывать метод split, создавая массив, - плохая идея. Использование ридеров - также не очень хорошая идея. Разумеется, это будет работать, однако читаемость кода оставляет желать лучшего. Их использование должно быть обусловленно задачей, потому как это в целом более гибкий и управляемый инструмент. В любых других "стандартных" случаях стоит использовать более высокоуровневые инструменты, к примеру, сканер.

И последнее... Ваш класс собрал в себе все, что только можно было придумать и затолкать. Так делать нельзя, настоятельно рекомендую реорганизовать код, пока еще не поздно))

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!! Вы очень помогли мне в изучении Java.